# draw infinite sine wave using UIBezier curve

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

i have task to draw a sin wave from user birthdate to infinite using UIBezier curve and i create it successfully using below code :

```
for (int i= 0; i<=app.noofDaysDifference; i++)
{

[path1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i*CWidth+100, 55-(sin(2*3.141592654*i/23))*CHeight)];

[path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i*CWidth+100, 55-(sin(2*3.141592654*i/28))*CHeight)];

[path3 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(i*CWidth+100, 55-(sin(2*3.141592654*i/33))*CHeight)];

 }

    [path2 setLineWidth:2.5];
    [path3 setLineWidth:2.5];
    [path1 setLineWidth:2.5];

    [[UIColor blueColor] set];
    [path1 stroke];
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [path2 stroke];
    [[UIColor greenColor] set];
    [path3 stroke];
```

but it take too much time to draw it due to no of Days. yes i have one more  idea that i should use queue technique like draw first 200 point then again 200 till no of days. so   would anyone suggest me any good logic that take short time to draw it .

Comment: Have it run asynchronously in the background?

Comment: since its UI things that not run in background , i have to draw it on Main thread....

Comment: How about just drawing enough of the wave to appear in the view and then shifting it. You know how wide the view is, how wide the wave is and you know it's periodicity. You don't need to draw the whole curve, just what will appear.

Comment: @Abizern yep this is good idea but don't  you think it would be leggy when user scroll it continue or fast.....

Comment: a)Compared to calculating an infinite curve? I doubt it. b)Don't guess at performance; profile it and compare.

Comment: @Abizern as per i say that when user scroll it fast then it would be leggy , yes its leggy and as per u told me that draw only what will appear , i did that and its leggy when i scroll it fast ...... please help..